# SQL insert ID to specific id another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I have 2 tables. 
I want to transfer some sql entries to another table.
13 is the catid in table1 but in table2 my catid is different.

```
table1                table2
catid  title alias    catid title  alias
13     abc   xyz       78    abc   xyz
13     test  test      78    test  test
```

Comment: Can u plz paste ur output table values after insertion. Means how should ur table2 look like after insertion.

Comment: @PankajK it will look like table2 - cat 13 all entries will come under catid 78 but all the table columns should be mention in a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it static, Do it like :-

```
INSERT INTO table1 (catid, title, alias) SELECT '2', title, alias FROM table2
```

Optionally, if you need where clause

```
WHERE catid ='13'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Use This Sql Query:

For Getting the data from table1:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE catid=13";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $title=$row["title"];
      $alias=$row["alias"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

For Inserting the data into table2:

update table table2 set title='$title', alias='$alias' where catid=78
```

Comment: the update query is fine but i want cat13 id should be transfer to catid 78

Comment: Do not use mysqli_ function with Joomla

Answer (score -1):

```
Use This Sql Query:

For Getting the data from table1:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE catid=13";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $catid=$row["catid"];
      $title=$row["title"];
      $alias=$row["alias"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

For Inserting the data into table2:

update table table2 set catid='$catid', title='$title', alias='$alias'  where catid=78
```

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_` function with Joomla